# AutoMapper Flattening without the name convention

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to flatten my Domain model into the Contract type

This is my Model:

```
public interface IPrice
{
    IItem Item { get; set; }
    Money Money {get; set;}
}

public interface IItem
{
    IItemHeader Header { get; set; }
}

public interface IItemHeader
{
    string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

and this is my Contract:

```
public class Price
{
  public string Name{ get; set; }  
}
```

Now, I know that if i will change the contract Name field to **ItemHeaderName** 
AutoMapper will handle that and will set the correct value when I map between IPrice and Price. but what if I don't like that name (i.e. ItemHeaderName) and insist on using "**Name**" instead? is there is any alternative?

Answer (score 2):

If you call it just Name, then you need MapFrom. You can also have a custom naming convention if the default one doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

We need to do something like that:

```
 CreateMap<Contract.Entities.Price, Model.Entities.IPrice>().
            ReverseMap().
            ForMember(model => model.Name, model => model.MapFrom(src => src.Item.Header.Name)).
```